# Python 3.3 Threading.Semaphore does not accept the verbose argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, billiards

I have a problem.
I want to use celery on python 3.3, I have installed this packet and it works fine.
But if I run it, there is a problem in the library of billiard. the first problem was that he didn't know the library _subproces. now I have change this to _winapi and now it works. But now I have another problem. on Python 3.3 Threading.Semaphor does not accept the verbose argument.

```
[2013-04-05 11:21:22,468: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError('__i
nit__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\__init__.py", line 205, in s
tart
    self.namespace.start(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 352, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 112, in
start
    self.on_start()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\processes.py", line 81,
 in on_start
    **self.options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.23-py3.3.egg\billiard\pool.
py", line 834, in __init__
    self._putlock = semaphore or LaxBoundedSemaphore(self._processes)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\billiard-2.7.3.23-py3.3.egg\billiard\pool.
py", line 136, in __init__
    _Semaphore.__init__(self, value, verbose)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Have anybody an idea to fix this problem???